# Scroll to status id via url link

Tags: php, url, scroll, status

i want after form process adding of some status to via link get scrolled on that div

```
<div id="sid-number">...</div>
```

and when finish process via url something like http://link.com/member/username/#status_id=hereid

I tryed all tuts but noting worked?

Answer (score 0):

The ID you use in the HTML must be the content of the hash value in the url.

In your case: http://example.com/thepage#sid-number

Note that this is literally "sid-number", because you have this string in your HTML example code.

Comment: example how to do this?

Comment: The URL in the form action is fixed - if you want to dynamically scroll to somewhere, you'd place the ID you use at the place you want to scroll. Alternatively, you can send redirect headers with the hash part in the URL (expect older browsers to ignore it).

Comment: I need something like facebook comment tracking ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954618/scroll-to-status-id-via-url-link/29954971?noredirect=1#comment48197296_29954971   i need just same script like here